# Pixabay jQuery autoComplete escape issue

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

[image]

I asked in repo's issues but am not getting an answer. https://github.com/Pixabay/jQuery-autoComplete/issues/65

The quotes get listed within the dropdown. But when selected am getting issues with the quotes(as seen in gif). I can't figure out how it even gets added to text input within the code. Am not strong enough in JS yet.

I can't justify pasting all the code from the script here. I hope that someone can take a look at the [repo](https://github.com/Pixabay/jQuery-autoComplete/issues/65) really quick and point me in the right direction.

This is where its initial string gets escaped

```
    renderItem: function (item, search){
        // escape special characters
        search = search.replace(/[$-\/?[-^{|}]/g, '\\$&');
        var re = new RegExp("(" + search.split(' ').join('|') + ")", "gi");
        return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-val="' + item + '">' + item.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>") + '</div>';
    },
```

Cant figure out were it goes from there, how is it getting added to that text input? How can make it escape once again.

I know am asking a lot, I spent a day trying to figure it out, but I'll be back at again tomorrow. Hopefully someone can spare 5 minutes take a look and help this suffering newb.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it myself, am sure in pertty sloppy way.

```
return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-val="' + item.replace("\"", "&quot;").replace("'", "&apos;") + '">' + item.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>") + '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, you can use this function:

`$(selector).text(notEscapedText)`

In your case:

```
renderItem: function (item, search){
    return $('<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-val="' + item + '">').text(search);
},
```

Or:

```
renderItem: function (item, search){
    var $value = $('<b>').text(search);

    return $('<div>')
        .addClass('autocomplete-suggestion')
        .data('val', item)
        .append($value);
},
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. Unfortunately am having a issue with that code. The dropdown is showing [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]